# rosserial Teensy bluetooth problem

Tags: ros, bluetooth, rosserial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to use rosserial with Teensy 3.5 through bluetooth.

My first step: change the serial port from Serial to Serial1.

I follow the thread:
https://answers.ros.org/question/198247/how-to-change-the-serial-port-in-the-rosserial-lib-for-the-arduino-side/?answer=295159#post-id-295159

It compiles with Arduino Mega board but no with Teensy 3.5 (or other Teensy boards)

---

I use:
Ubuntu 16.04, Kinetic ros, Arduino 1.8.5
The Hello World example code:
http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World

---

I tried to ways:

1. Modify the line 73 in the code arduino.1.8.5/libraries/ros_lib/ArduinoHardware.h

iostream = &Serial1;

2. Replace:

   ros::NodeHandle nh;

with:

```
class NewHardware : public ArduinoHardware
{
  public:
  NewHardware():ArduinoHardware(&Serial1, 57600){};
};
ros::NodeHandle_<NewHardware>  nh;
```

---

The error when I try to compile is:

```
.../arduino-1.8.5/libraries/ros_lib/ArduinoHardware.h:67:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'HardwareSerial*' to 'usb_serial_class*'
no matching function for call to 'ArduinoHardware::ArduinoHardware(HardwareSerial*, int)'
```

---

ArduinoHardware.h:
http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/rosserial_arduino/html/ArduinoHardware_8h_source.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295163/rosserial-teensy-bluetooth-problem/) by [jordiguerrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/36060/jordiguerrero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-06-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-24**:
What is your original problem (i.e., please update your question with a copy and paste of the error)? Why are you modifying the source code of a library? Can you please update your question with a copy and paste of of the code that you wrote?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-25**:
@jordiguerrero: please post your last edit as an answer, and then accept your own answer.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-25**:
Also: I don't see `#define USE_TEENSY_HW_SERIAL` in your last edit?

**Comment by [jordiguerrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/36060/jordiguerrero/) on 2018-06-25**:
Ok, I make the changes. Sorry about any inconvenient, it is my first post...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-25**:
No need to apologise. Just keep it in mind for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

SOLVED:
I forget to add the next include:

`#define USE_USBCON`

It was solved in the teensy forum, thank you to Theremingenieur user:
https://forum.pjrc.com/threads/52928-rosserial-bluetooth-teensy-problem

The modified Hello World sample:

```
/*
 * rosserial Publisher Example
 * Prints "hello world!"
 */

// Use the following line if you have a Leonardo or MKR1000 
#define USE_USBCON


#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

//ros::NodeHandle nh;
class NewHardware : public ArduinoHardware
{
  public:
  NewHardware():ArduinoHardware(&Serial1, 57600){};
};
ros::NodeHandle_<NewHardware>  nh;

std_msgs::String str_msg;
ros::Publisher chatter("chatter", &str_msg);

char hello[13] = "hello world!";

void setup()
{
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(chatter);
}

void loop()
{
  str_msg.data = hello;
  chatter.publish( &str_msg );
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1000);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [jordiguerrero](https://answers.ros.org/users/36060/jordiguerrero/) with karma: 16 on 2018-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0